# Is 甘じている a typo? (example sentence)

Tags: spelling, okurigana

> 会社では外様の地位に甘じている。　
>   He is reconciled to 「being outside of [not belonging to] the mainstream faction at the company.
>   <sub>(Source: [dictionary.goo.ne.jp](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/54409/m1u/%E5%A4%96%E6%A7%98/))</sub>

I wasn't able to find 甘じる or 甘ずる verb in dictionaries I looked at. Is it a typo of 甘んじる?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this is an example sentence in a modern J-E dictionary, yes, I believe this is a typo. At least in standard Japanese, it should be written as 甘んじている.

[BCCWJ corpus](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/) returned only one result for 甘【あまん】じる ("屈辱に甘じているのだ" in a novel published in 2002), and there may be a few other instances where old writers used 甘【あまん】じる. But let's not care about that too much.